# Looping through a String in SPARQL

Tags: loops, iteration, sparql, rdf

I have strings that are attributes of a property in my ontology like: "Foo1 hasBar Bar1, Foo2 hasBaz Baz1,..."

What I want to do is to loop through the string turning each triple separated by a comma into an actual triple. BTW, I know the first thought may be "why didn't you just process the data that way with an upload tool like Cellfie" or "call the SPARQL query from a programming language" but for my particular client they would rather just use SPARQL and the ontology is already a given.

I have written a query that does what I want for the first triple and changes the string to remove that triple. E.g., it finds the first triple, turns that into rdf and inserts it into the graph and then changes the original string property to: "Foo2 hasBaz Baz1,..."

So I can just run the query until there are no more strings to process but that's kind of a pain. I've looked through the SPARQL documentation and the examples regarding SPARQL and iteration on this site and I just don't think it is possible given the declarative nature of SPARQL but I wanted to double check. Perhaps if I did something like embed the current query in another query?

Comment: technically not possible but with limitations a regex works. The query is a sketch for at most 20 triples in the string literal. All you have to do is to use this inside your `CONSTRUCT` query to produce proper RDF triples.

Comment: comments: `?n` is max number of triples inside the string being parsed; 
`?data` some sample data;  
`BIND (CONCAT("^([^,]*,){", str(?n) ,"} *") AS ?skip_n)` builds the regex which skips n triples;  
`BIND (REPLACE(REPLACE(?data, ?skip_n, ""), ",.*$", "") AS ?triple)`  applies regex and omits any triples following;  the last part extract the triple components

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?predicate ?object { BIND("^([^\\s]+)\\s+([^\\s]+)\\s+?([^\\s]+)?$" AS ?triple_regex) VALUES ?n { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 } VALUES ?data {"Foo1 hasBar Bar1, Foo2 hasBaz Baz1,  Foo2 hasBaz Baz2"} BIND (CONCAT("^([^,]*,){", str(?n) ,"} *") AS ?skip_n)  BIND (REPLACE(REPLACE(?data, ?skip_n, ""), ",.*$", "") AS ?triple)   BIND (REPLACE(?triple, ?triple_regex, "$1") AS ?subject) BIND (REPLACE(?triple, ?triple_regex, "$2") AS ?predicate) BIND (REPLACE(?triple, ?triple_regex, "$3") AS ?object) }`